# Include ActiveAdmin in gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, activeadmin

I'm working on a small rails engine with I have turned into a gem. In order to manage the database I want to use ActiveAdmin.

I've added ActiveAdmin to my list of gem dependencies, and when I install the gem in my application I copy the active_admin initializer to config/initializers/ in the project which is using the gem.

However - for some reason this makes the application fail with the error:

```
uninitialized constant ActiveAdmin
```

If I add "activeadmin" to the projects Gemfile it run great - but that's wrong and I don't understand why I need to do that. I want my gem to be as isolated as possible.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: I suppose you did not restart the server. Is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to manually require activeadmin from your gem's railtie (Rails 3.x) or initializer (Rails 2.x). Also it might be wise to move your config/initializers/active_admin.rb to engine as well. Something like this for Rails 3.x (put it into lib/my_gem/engine.rb)

```rb
require 'activeadmin' 

class MyGem::Engine < Rails::Engine
  initializer do
     # Do the same what you did in config/initializers/ of rails project
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you. I have to admit I was just out eating dinner when I realized I forgot to require it. But thank you for answering anyway :)

However - I do have a follow up question if you don't mind. I added the require part but now I'm getting this error: "uninitialized constant MyModule::Admin".

Comment: i have that same issue, and I don't have a clue about how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Is MyModule::Admin your class? What is its path in gem? If it is not in app/ dir you might need to add the following to lib/my_module.rb

```
    module MyModule
      extend ActiveSupport::Autoload
      autoload :Admin
    end
```

Comment: No, it's not my class - I assume its a part of ActiveAdmin which my gem thinks should be in MyModule:: but really just is outside.